# Python: make subclass of generic class generic by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, python-typing

I want to be able to define what the contents of **a subclass of a subclass** of `typing.Iterable` have to be.
Type hints are critical for this project so I have to find a working solution

Here is a snip code of what I've already tried and what I want:

```python
# The code I'm writing:
from typing import TypeVar, Iterable

T = TypeVar('T')


class Data:
    pass


class GeneralPaginatedCursor(Iterable[T]):
    """
    If this type pf cursor is used by an EDR a specific implementation has to be created
    Handle paginated lists, exposes hooks to simplify retrieval and parsing of paginated data
    """
    # Implementation
    pass


###########
# This part is supposed to be written by different developers on a different place:


class PaginatedCursor(GeneralPaginatedCursor):
    pass


def foo() -> GeneralPaginatedCursor[Data]:
    """
    Works great
    """
    pass


def bar() -> PaginatedCursor[Data]:
    """
    Raises
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    .
    .
    .
        def bar(self) -> PaginatedCursor[Data]:
    File "****\Python\Python38-32\lib\typing.py", line 261, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwds)
    File "****\Python\Python38-32\lib\typing.py", line 894, in __class_getitem__
        _check_generic(cls, params)
    File "****\Python\Python38-32\lib\typing.py", line 211, in _check_generic
        raise TypeError(f"{cls} is not a generic class")
    """
    pass
```

I don't want to leave it to the other developers in the future to inherit from `Iterable` because if someone will miss it everything will break.

---

I found the exact same issue here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/82640
But there is no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only requirements are that `GeneralPaginatedCursor` define `__iter__` to return an `Iterable` value (namely, something with a `__next__` method).

The error you see occurs because, since `GeneralPaginatedCursor` is generic in `T`, `PaginatedCursor` should be as well.

```
class PaginatedCursor(GeneralPaginatedCursor[T]):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you  for the answer but there is still a problem..
Regarding the first part:
"The only requirements are that GeneralPaginatedCursor define __iter__ to return an Iterable value (namely, something with a __next__ method)."
The real code does implement all the relevant methods so this is not an issue.
The issue is that I really don't want to relay on the other developers to add 

`from typing import TypeVar`
`T = TypeVar('T')`
`class PaginatedCursor(GeneralPaginatedCursor[T]):`
.
.
for every implementation (unless there is no other option at all).

Comment: You have it backwards. You aren't *relying* on them to do anything. You are simply *requiring* them to use generic classes properly.

Comment: This actually makes more sense.
So now only for knowledge prepuces, are you saying that there is no way of inheriting it?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to implicitly propogate the genericity of a class.

Comment: Actually, if other devs **do not** want to use generics properly, they do not want to use annotations, right? You do not *require* TypeVar usage by those who do not want to use type checkers (as many of us, obviously), because without an annotation no error is raised. And those who want are aware of proper generics handling anyway. Plus string annotations or `from __future__ import annotations` prevent this error from appearing as well. So the circumstances you describe are almost impossible: either other devs annotate properly, or they do not at all, + annotations future is de-facto standard.